# VlcControl is always on the top of the Grid

Tags: .net, wpf, vlc

I need to put `VlcControl` inside the `Grid` with other `Grid` that contains menu controls, but regardless `VlcControl` is always in top of parent `Grid`.

```
 <Grid> 
 <Grid x:Name="VideoHolder"> 
 <vlc:VlcControl /> 
 </Grid> 

 <Grid x:Name="MenuHolder"> 
 <!— content —> 
 </Grid> 
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? do you want content to be on top of the video?

Comment: I suspect the best you will be able to do is to use a Popup control for the part over the VLC control because of the way video is rendered on the screen. If it is a menu perhaps is not a big issue?

Comment: @mhttk: it is not actualy a menu. `<!- content ->` represents the containter of other WPF controls Buttons, Slider e. t. c...

Comment: I've added a code sample to my answer. I can switch the zindex to get what change the zorder

Comment: Actually, @mhttk might be on to something. There are airspace issues when dealing with these sorts of things. I.e. WinformsHost.

Comment: A long time ago I had to overlay some text over a video stream and then I realised that that particular control (was not VLC) was always on top of ther controls no matter what. I ended writing directX calls to display my overlay text. A popup is a new window so that might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the attached property `Panel.ZIndex="NUMBER"`  on the named grids, the one that you want on top should have the bigger number. say `Panel.ZIndex="2"`

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="VideoHolder" Panel.ZIndex="2">
        <Border Background="AliceBlue" Height="100" Width="300"  />
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="MenuHolder" Panel.ZIndex="1">
        <Border Background="Beige" Margin="50,0,0,0" Height="100" Width="300" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: still nothing changes.

Comment: Still not working. I think it may be some sort of WinFormsHost issue, but I am not sure.

Comment: It is an wpf/win32 airspace issue then. The snippet I provided works, given that the content is basic wpf ala borders.

Comment: And what did you suggest to deal with the wpf/win32 airspace issue.

Comment: There really isn't a proper solution. Many work arounds involve rendering the win32 content off screen (your video) and then rendering it back onto a WPF element. DirectX is one way, C++ GDI is another way, and https://microsoftdwayneneed.codeplex.com/ as a third. I've used all three in different contexts.

Comment: None of them 100% satisfying.  I'd suggest trying to put a WinformsHost (or HwndHost from dwayneneed) onto a Popup as one of the other.  If it works then you manually try to position it as you want it.

Answer (score 2):

If that suits your needs you can try to use a popup like in the snippet below.

Please be aware that probably you won't be able to have the transparency working.

```
<Grid>
     <vlc:VlcControl x:Name="VideoHolder"/>
     <Popup Height="Auto"
            AllowsTransparency="True"
            IsOpen="True"
            PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=VideoHolder}">
                    <Border Background="White">
                      ...
                    </Border>
     </Popup>
 </Grid>
```

for the inkCanvas

```
<Grid>
     <vlc:VlcControl x:Name="VideoHolder" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
     <InkCanvas Panel.ZIndex="2">

     </InkCanvas>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Still not working. I think it may be some sort of WinFormsHost issue, but I am not sure.

Comment: next step I would try is to use an InkCanvas perhaps